# Custom Rails Validation not adding 'field_with_errors' wrapper to inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 site with a form that needed some custom validation. But when the validation criteria fails and the error message is shown, the input fields I'm checking aren't given the field_with_errors wrapper. All other fields being validated are getting the wrapper properly, but their validation is a simple presence check on each attribute.

How can I have the wrapper added in with my custom validation?

Additional notes: I'd like to only show my error message once, if possible - but highlight both fields.

In my model:

```
validate :at_least_one_apply_method

def at_least_one_apply_method
  if [self.apply_url, self.application_instructions].reject(&:blank?).size == 0
    errors[:base] << ("Please provide at least one: Where to Apply or Applications Instructions.")
  end
end
```

Let me know of any other information needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the custom error message to errors[:base]. You need to add it to the field which you want to be wrapped e.g.

```
errors[:apply_url] << ("Please provide at least one: Where to Apply or Applications Instructions.")
errors[: application_instructions] << ("Please provide at least one: Where to Apply or Applications Instructions.")
```

Comment: Gotcha -- but I was originally using base so that it didn't insert the field name into the message. Now it will read "Apply url Please provide at least one: Where to Apply or Applications Instructions." - is there another way I can exclude the field name? Also, can I have just a single error message show up instead of two?

Comment: hmm, you could go back to what you had originally and use javascript to add the error class to the fields you want highlighted. And no, you dont need to add both error messages to the errors hash.

Answer (score 0):

Errors message are only bind to filed if **object.errors** hash have key of that field name.
But you are adding custom message with the key of **base**.

So you can do like below

```
validate :at_least_one_apply_method

def at_least_one_apply_method
  [self.apply_url, self.application_instructions].map{|field| field.blank? ? (self.errors.add("field","Please provide at least one: Where to Apply or Applications Instructions.")
  ") : ''}
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this as it's written isn't working properly. I think there's an extra quote before the last closing parenthesis? Also mine required an additional "end".

Comment: Even so -- It doesn't seem to be validating properly. It isn't wrapping the fields with the error class as expected, and it isn't checking for one of the other - it's requiring both. Have a misunderstood your answer?