# div wrapper with class field_with_errors not being added after failing validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `bootstrap-sass` gem.  I have a validation that requires a selection for a select box.

Here is the select box:

[image: select box]

The validation specifies that a selection must be made (but it does `include_blank` so that the select box starts out empty).  After failing validation here is what it should look like:

[image: failing validation style].

Rails should create a div that wraps the input's label and select box with the class `field_with_errors`.  However, for whatever reason: rails is not doing this with these select boxes.  It is working properly for my form's text boxes but, just not the select boxes.

I can manually add in that div wrapper with the `field_with_errors` class and it works fine.  So it appears that the problem is that rails is just not creating that div wrapper with that class.

Here is the relevant part of the form:

```
<div class= 'row'>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <%= f.label :foo_id, class:'control-label' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-asterisk label_required"></i>
      Expense Type
    <% end %>
    <%= f.collection_select :foo_id, Foo.all, :id, :description, {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**:  How can I make it so that upon validation failure, rails will add that div wrapper with the class `field_with_errors` to my invalid `collection_select` fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Rails Validation not adding 'field\_with\_errors' wrapper to inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482443/custom-rails-validation-not-adding-field-with-errors-wrapper-to-inputs)

Comment: @shelvacu  I think (but I'm not certain) that this question isn't an exact duplicate of the nominated exemplar: The answers to that question and this questions are different enough to suggest that this is a distinct question.

Comment: @shelvacu I agree with Wayne that this question is different from your suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with how I named the `validation`.  Assume that the form is for a `bar` model, and I have that `collection_select` on `foo`:

```
#models/bar.rb
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo

  validates :foo_id, presence: true
end
```

I previously had the validation like this:

```
validates :foo, presence: true
```

Validating `foo` as opposed to properly validating `foo_id` made it properly fail and display the error message, but rails had trouble adding the div wrapper with `field_with_errors`.  By instead validating `foo_id` it properly validates, displays the error message, AND adds the div wrapper.