# Proper generation of Rails' field_with_errors for select list of belongs_to during validation failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

[[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662837/div-wrapper-with-class-field-with-errors-not-being-added-after-failing-validatio) would have been all right for older versions of Rails, but not since `belongs_to` is required by default.]

Given I have a WorkOrder model and a Customer model, where the WorkOrder `belongs_to` a Customer:

```
class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
```

And a typical select list in the work order form:

```
= form.collection_select :customer_id, customers, :id, :full_name, {include_blank: ''}, class: 'form-select'
```

When I do not select a customer, the validation fails since `belongs_to` requires an associated Customer in order for the WorkOrder to be valid. Ok. But then, when the form renders with the error, I do not see that the select list is wrapped with the usual `field_with_errors` element. As such, while the main error message about "Customer must exist" is there, the select list is not bordered in red.

This is because the error message key is on `customer`, and not `customer_id`, and the select list is for `customer_id`.

If I add a validator for `customer_id` to the WorkOrder model:

```
class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  validates :customer_id, presence: true
```

Then the select list does get wrapped with `field_with_errors` and appears with a red border. However, now the error messages report "2 errors prohibited..." instead of "1 error prohibited...". In addition, the error messages are redundant: One states "Customer must exist" and another states "Customer can't be blank."

I can remove the validator for `:customer_id` and change the select tag to use `customer`:

```
= form.collection_select :customer, customers, :id, :full_name, {include_blank: ''}
```

But this isn't correct, since the field needs to use the name of the attribute, `customer_id`.

Instead, I could make a change in the model:

```
class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, optional: true
  validates :customer_id, presence: true
```

But this is redundant in the model and feels wrong: the association is *not* optional, nor do I want it to be. The optionality followed by a presence validator feels like a hack.

Lastly, I could keep the model clean:

```
class WorkOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
```

And then in the view, inspect the errors:

```
<% if form.object.errors.include?(:customer) %>
  <div class='field_with_errors'>
<% end %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :customer_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :customer_id, customers, :id, :full_name, {include_blank: ''} %>
  </div>
<% if form.object.errors.include?(:customer) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And this works, but is now an ugly hack in the view.

I'd like to have a normal `belongs_to` relationship and I would like Rails to generate a proper `field_with_errors` around a select element just like it does with text fields.

What is the proper way to get this behavior? (I swear Rails used to do this out of the box, but perhaps not, since `belongs_to` used to be optional by default, and we used to have to have the explicit presence validator on the foreign key attribute.)

[image]